# Find the total distinct 4 letter code arrangments

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

how many distinct 4-letter code words can be made from the letters in the word ALGEBRA?

Hello, I am currently competing in what is known as UIL Mathematics, a competitive Math event. I have tried the theory of getting the total amount of letters followed by "!" and dividing by the repeating letters followed by "!" but this didn't give the answer. I did this: 7!/2!. Please help.

Comment: Your answer counts the number of ways to arrange ALL of the letters into a word. What we need is to find the number of ways we pick only $4$ letter words. Perhaps the hint given by JMoravitz will point you in the right direction

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:*

How many ways can you choose a four letter code using letters from the word `ALGEBR`

The above codes will all have zero or one `A`.

Now, how many ways can you choose a four letter code where there are exactly two `A`'s being used and the remaining two letters are taken from `LGEBR`.

Answer (score 0):

Following @JMoravitz's hint, there should be

> $P^6_4+P^5_2\cdot C^4_2=360+20\cdot6=480$.